# Animation using Animator 0.1.2 stopped working

Tags: animation

I'm using the Animator 0.1.2 package to make a raised button rotate on it's axis. All of a sudden it just stopped working. Has anyone else experienced this? I even tried an earlier version of my app in case I changed or deleted something and it doesn't work there anymore either. Weird (and frustrating)!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the logic to stop my animation didn't work anymore. I had to code this differently and I got it working again.